# Cannot Stick Last Header at top using AngularJS Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive called , When the user scrolls through the list, the header must show at top of the list until the next one is reached.
The problem is getting when I reach at the last header it won't stick at the top, that also scroll with page.

**my custom directive**

```
  angular.module('myApp', []) 
   .directive('packageHeader', ['$window', function($window){
     var stickies = [],
      scroll = function scroll() {

      angular.forEach(stickies, function($sticky, index) {

            var sticky = $sticky[0],
            pos = $sticky.data('pos');

        if (pos <= $window.pageYOffset) {
          var $next = stickies[index + 1],              
              next = $next ? $next[0] : null,
              npos = $next.data('pos');  

              $sticky.addClass("fixed");

          if (next && next.offsetTop >= npos - next.clientHeight)
            $sticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", npos - sticky.clientHeight + 'px');
        } else {
          var $prev = stickies[index - 1],
              prev = $prev ? $prev[0] : null;

          $sticky.removeClass("fixed");

          if (prev && $window.pageYOffset <= pos - prev.clientHeight)
            $prev.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      });
    },

    //link function
  link = function($scope, element, attrs) {
        var sticky = element.children()[0],
            $sticky = angular.element(sticky);

        element.css('height', sticky.clientHeight + 'px');

        $sticky.data('pos', sticky.offsetTop);
        stickies.push($sticky);
      };

angular.element($window).off('scroll', scroll).on('scroll', scroll);

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  //sticky - getting from style sheet
  template: '<sticky ng-transclude></sticky>',
  link: link
}; 
   }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">   
   <div>  
   <package-header>
   <div>Header First</div>
  </package-header>
<div class="whitespace">     
  Header First with content............. First Header 
</div>
 </div>
<div>   
<package-header>
  <div> Header Second </div>      
  </package-header> 
<div class="whitespace">    
  Header second with content............. Second Header 
</div>
```

Here i'm attaching my code https://plnkr.co/edit/VFyGlNk2641rg31nCq8O?p=preview

I want the last header also show at top.
Please help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working just fine with corrected indexes for prev/next sticky elements:

https://embed.plnkr.co/B1ispK1gfMF3b85jDgkW/

Comment: This should be a comment. please read : [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).